# Readthedocs.org contribution, Error installing readthedocs locally

Tags: docker, installation, pip, dockerfile, read-the-docs

I am following the development guide on https://dev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html to install read the docs locally on **GitHub CodeSpace**

I fail at the step `inv docker.build`

It returns errors that says the 2 repositories **readthedocs-ext** and **ext-theme** is missing.

```
=> ERROR [17/18] RUN if [ -n "ghu_SX4JnJT78fsWDEnedKpml66eDt4sQ71bx7rp" ] ;         then         git clone --depth 1 https://ghu_SX4JnJT78fsWDEnedKpml66eDt4sQ71bx7rp@github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-ext ;      2.6s

> [17/18] RUN if [ -n "ghu_SX4JnJT78fsWDEnedKpml66eDt4sQ71bx7rp" ] ;         then         git clone --depth 1 https://ghu_SX4JnJT78fsWDEnedKpml66eDt4sQ71bx7rp@github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-ext ;         pip3 install --no-cache-dir -e readthedocs-ext ;         git clone --depth 1 https://ghu_SX4JnJT78fsWDEnedKpml66eDt4sQ71bx7rp@github.com/readthedocs/ext-theme ;         pip3 install --no-cache-dir -e ext-theme ;         fi:

#22 0.509 Cloning into 'readthedocs-ext'...
#22 0.914 remote: Repository not found.
#22 0.914 fatal: repository 'https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-ext/' not found
#22 1.396 ERROR: readthedocs-ext is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).
#22 1.475 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
#22 1.475 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
#22 1.558 Cloning into 'ext-theme'...
#22 1.833 remote: Repository not found.
#22 1.833 fatal: repository 'https://github.com/readthedocs/ext-theme/' not found
#22 2.295 ERROR: ext-theme is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).
#22 2.374 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
#22 2.374 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c if [ -n "$GITHUB_TOKEN" ] ;         then         git clone --depth 1 https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-ext ;         pip3 install --no-cache-dir -e readthedocs-ext ;         git clone --depth 1 https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/readthedocs/ext-theme ;         pip3 install --no-cache-dir -e ext-theme ;         fi]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'server' failed to build : Build failed
```

I have been stuck at this step for more than 2 days despite trying numerous ways.

Comment: Have you tried it without providing a github token?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try to see how to remove the GITHUB_TOKEN. Since I am using Github Codespace and not my own computer, it will take some research. Thank you for giving me suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The `GITHUB_TOKEN` is only for Core Team developers to install some private dependencies. You don't have to pass it if you want to contribute to Read the Docs.

Don't worry, your instance will be fully usable with all the features.